# ActiveAdmin - action "show" not working on composite_primary_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I have a table in PostgreSQL like given below.

```
user_id TEXT  
dept TEXT  
remarks TEXT  

Indexes:"college_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id, dept)
```

I'm trying to show this table in ActiveAdmin. The action `show` is causing an error. The error message is given below

**Error message**:

```
["user_id", "dept"] is not a symbol nor a string
 name, klass = "", self.class
 name << klass.model_name.human 
 if klass.respond_to? :model_name
 name << " ##{send(klass.primary_key)}"
 if klass.respond_to? :primary_key
 name.present? ? name : to_s}
 def DISPLAY_NAME_FALLBACK.inspect
```

I could easily view this table When I use `:id` as primary key. But when I added *composite_primary_key*, this error is showing.

Answer (score 1):

That's not even close to a question.

However.. change line 5 of your post to:

`Indexes: "college_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (:user_id, :dept)`